# Error while adding Firebase to android using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins

I am trying to add Firebase to the android app using Cordova to implement push notification.
so for I was able to add 'google-services.json' to the root of the project.

however when I am trying to build an android app using the command

> cmd>cordova build

it's giving me following error.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0.

this is occurring despite adding google play services plugin to Cordova.

I am new to hybrid app building , please help me on this.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need 'Android support Repository'. Open sdk manager check weather this is installed or not. Install/Update it. If already installed, you may need to uninstall and reinstall Android support repository. then restart your PC

You may also install google play services and google repository. many plugins may require these two.

Comment: After adding 'Android support Repository'  and 'google play services'  i am still getting the same error, and i am not able to find command  for  cordova to add 'google repository'.

Comment: command to add 'google repository'??? how did you added 'android support repository' in the first place? you need to open android sdk manager and install/update these items. if installed then you may need to uninstall and reinstall these three. then restart your pc?